# JODA Period not return correct value?

Tags: java, jodatime

Does this  return from the JODA API make sense?

```
DateTime sd = new DateTime(1973,1,1,0,0,0);
DateTime ed = new DateTime(1973,1,31,23,59,59);
Period p = new Period(sd,ed);

StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
buf.append(p.getYears()).append(" years ")
        .append(p.getMonths()).append(" months ")
        .append(p.getDays()).append(" days");
System.out.println(buf.toString());
```

returns 0 years 0 months 2 days?

Comment: You are not printing the number of weeks which is 4.

Comment: Can JODA not convert the 4 weeks 2 days to 1 month in this case?

Comment: `sd` and `ed` are in the same month so I wouldn't expect there to be months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `PeriodFormatter`:

```
System.out.println(PeriodFormat.getDefault().print(p));
```

Output:

```
4 weeks, 2 days, 23 hours, 59 minutes and 59 seconds
```

Comment: Can JODA not convert the 4 weeks 2 days to 1 month in this case?

Comment: Why should it? It's missing a second to be a month.

Comment: Makes sense. However adding a second to the end date (ed.plusSeconds(1)) before displaying did not change the results